# Xcode 4.1 not adding library for BCTabBarViewController

Tags: xcode, xcode4.1

I wanted to try out [BCTabBarController](https://github.com/briancollins/BCTabBarController) and added the files to my test-project by:

1. Dragging the BCTabBarController.xcodeproj onto my project in the project navigator.
2. Going to my project/target/Build Phases/Target Dependencies and adding BCTabbarController     (little house icon)
3. Going to project/target/Build Phases/Link Binaries With Libraries and add the libBCTabbarCOntroller.

Usually when I add a library like this, the .a library file will show up in my project navigator (and I drag it to frameworks to keep things tidy).

Strangely enough this did not happen with the libBCTabbarController.a file, it was nowhere.
And surely enough, the BCTabBarController.h header is not recognized anywhere.

**What can cause this behavior?** 
My debugging options are pretty limited, but I suspect that Xcode 4.1 finds something about the library it does not "like" and does not add it to my project.

Comment: It would be a lot easier to just use the source code files in your current project then trying to build a library, import it, etc.  Then that way you can customize the source if you desire, without having to rebuild the lib/framework and re-import it.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up doing just that after scratching my head for a few hours.

Comment: i i want to use BCTabbarcontroller in my project ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select the BCTabbar as a target and build it .then repeat the above it would add

Comment: Thanks, just went back and did this. It works. In the meantime I had gone with chown's suggestion, but yours is the answers to the question:)

Answer (score 1):

It would be a lot easier to just use the source code files in your current project then trying to build a library, import it, etc. Then that way you can customize the source if you desire, without having to rebuild the lib/framework and re-import it.